# Making jquery slider fullscreen and with html 5 elements?

Tags: jquery, html

Before I embark on this long task of writing jquery slider fullscreen for html5 I wonder if any of you have done this before, or know of plugin that can accomplish this?

When size is fixed it is easy to acomplish this, but how do you make full screen slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this recently using the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) on the [pixolith](http://pixolith.de) site. Just ensure that the width of the slider is 100%.